# Is there a way to install GRUB to sdb on an install from USB on RHEL 6?

Tags: linux, rhel, usb, system-installation, grub

I'm doing an installation of RHEL 6 using a USB drive.  It works great, but every time I want to use the computer, I have to have the USB inserted.  On the installation, the USB is sda and the target hard drive is sdb.  GRUB gets installed to the USB every time (sda).  So, is there a way to do an installation of RHEL where it installs GRUB to sdb (the target where RHEL is being installed)?  I think RHEL installs it to sda by default every time.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There should be a way to change the boot loader device. You can see it in step 13 here: https://www.tecmint.com/red-hat-enterprise-linux-rhel-6-installation-guide-with-screenshots/

Comment: Ahh, yeah I am doing a text installation and that isn't an option.  Maybe it's an option I can set in a kickstart file or as a boot option when I install?

Answer (score 1):

Unless told otherwise, GRUB assumes that the first disk detected by the installer will also be the first disk detected by the system firmware. On CD or network installations, this heuristic usually works (unless you have multiple storage controllers).

But when your installation media is USB, the RHEL 6 installer detects it first before any other storage devices. If you are setting up a kickstart installation, you can definitely tell it to write the bootloader to `/dev/sdb` instead. It's done by using the `--driveorder` option of the `bootloader` keyword: if you're booting the installer from USB, you must specify the disk the OS will be installed in as the first disk in the drive order, i.e.

```
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=sdb,sda <...>
```

The logic may feel a bit odd here. It is because the option is really trying to identify which disk the system BIOS will see as the "first disk" when booting the installed system, since the de-facto BIOS standard way to select the disk to boot from  is to place it as the first disk in the order seen by BIOS. But the --driveorder option must use the Linux device names as they exist at the time of the installation... which won't necessarily be the same as when the installed system is running.

Essentially, we must tell the installer "once the system is installed and booting on its own, what is now `/dev/sdb` will be the first disk".

This will be enough to install the bootloader successfully to the target hard drive. But it will also leave the installed system with a `/boot/grub/device.map` file that indicates that the first disk will be `/dev/sdb`... which will most likely no longer be true once the system boots with the USB drive unplugged. This will bite you if/when you need to update the GRUB package, causing the bootloader to fail after an upgrade.

However, the solution is simple: if you're building a Kickstart installation for USB, just set up a post-install command to delete the `/boot/grub/device.map` file after the installation is complete. It can be as simple as:

```
%post
rm /boot/grub/device.map

%end
```

If `/boot/grub/device.map` does not exist, the `grub-install` command will automatically recreate it if/when it is run the next time... and then it will be much more likely to make the correct choice. If you want to be absolutely sure, you can verify the situation after the installation is complete and the system has rebooted, and write an accurate `/boot/grub/device.map` file manually.

Comment: Great, thanks for the response.  I will give this a shot and will respond back here with the result details.  Thanks again. :)